# Change in internal energy of ideal gas getting released into a vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

So im working on a homework problem that states:

For the container shown on the right, initially, there is 1 mole of ideal gas in part A, and part B is vacuum (VA=VB). After the division is suddenly removed, an equilibrium is finally reached. a) Calculate the change of the internal energy; b) What is the change of the entropy for the gas?

I know that to find internal energy we use delta U = delta Q - delta W, I also know that delta W = PdV. According to my book that talks about a similar situation it states that delta W would be zero since the gas performs no work on its external surroundings. but wouldn't it not be zero since the volume changes from Va to Va+Vb?

Comment: Is the container rigid or isn’t it?

Comment: I believe it is rigid

Comment: How can the gas do work on a rigid container?

Answer (score 1):

The equations $\delta W = -pdV$ and $\delta Q = T dS$ hold only for reversible processes. This process is clearly irreversible so you have to figure things out another way. In this case, work has to be 0 because there is no object on which the gas could perform the work.

Comment: but couldn't work be done in order to get the system back to where it was? or is a reversible process only valid for engines since it will eventually cycle back to its original state?

Comment: You would have to do work to recompress the gas because the gas is in the way. But no work is done expanding into a vacuum because there’s nothing in the way. (This kind of asymmetry arises often with irreversible processes.)